# FORTRAN code with ascii data

Tags: fortran

I have a data in ASCII format (.txt file) in which date is given in a column in format yearmonthday (i.e.19900601). I want to separate this column into three columns with year, month and date in each column. Can anyone tell how to do this in Fortran? My data file and code is as following:

datum nied
19480501 -1
19480502 -1
19480503 2
19480504 -1
19480505 2
19480506 -1
19480507 -1
19480508 -1
19480509 -1
19480510 -1
19480511 -1
19480512 2
  .       .
  .       .

**Code:**

```
program ascii_read    
!real(kind=8):: rain(np)    
real,allocatable:: rain(:)    
integer::np=15739  
!integer(kind=8)::day(np)  
integer,allocatable::day(:)  
character(len = 80)::firstline  
integer::i,j  
integer,allocatable:: year(:)  
allocate (year(np-1))  
allocate (rain(np))  
allocate (day(np))  
open(1243,file="11700.text",status="unknown")
open(12,file="11700_output.text",status="unknown")
read(1243,*)firstline  

do i=2,np  
read(1243,1111)day(i),rain(i)  
end do  
1111 Format(i6,F5.2)  
write(*,*)day    
do j = 1,np-1  
year(j)=day(j)   
end do   
write(*,fmt='(i4)')year    
1 format(I4)  
!write(*,*)year  
return    
stop   
end program
```

This gives only year separate in a column,NOT month and day. Any idea how to separate month and day from this data file?

Comment: did any of the answers below help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete mine to save people from wasting their time looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "hybrid" approach of the other two answers is to first read in the data into a buffer and then split it into integers

```
character(50) buf
integer year, month, day, rain

read( 10, * ) buf, rain
read( buf, "(i4,i2,i2)" ) year, month, day

! or equivalently
! read( buf(1:4), * ) year
! read( buf(5:6), * ) month
! read( buf(7:8), * ) day
```

Here, list-directed I/O is used to skip possible spaces before the first column, while integers are extracted based on widths. Also, comment lines starting with "#" (if any) can be skipped by inserting `if ( buf(1:1) == "#" ) cycle` after the first read statement, for example.

Comment: Thanks everyone..I got the desired data file with your help :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use a formatted read to explicitly pull out each of the fields:

```
integer year,month,day,rain

...

read(1234,'(i4,i2,i2,i3)')year,month,day,rain
```

In your code you use `i6` so `day(i)` holds things like '194805', then `rain(i)` is read from the remainder of the line (ie. the last two digits of the "date" integer a space and another integer).  I don't know what the `f5.2` format does with that but it can't be what you want)

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Because the data file has two columns and the program will take only two formatting statements, one for integer ix (x=2 or 4 or 6) and the second as real. (Data file has 1st column integer and second column real)

Comment: with formatting you don't worry about space delimited columns and directly read character positions.  My code is verified to work. What error do you get?  There are no reals (no decimal points) in your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked finally :) I was getting some runtime error but I solved it! This was very easy. Once again thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to analyse the relationship between your input and the output that you want and then implement the relationship; that is how programming works. You have to first know a method to solve the problem by yourself and then teach the computer how to do it.
For this problem, you can simply see that the first 4 digits represent the year, the next two the month and the last 2 the date. To get the first 4, you divide the full number by 10000, it simply reject the last 4 (month and day). You use the modulo operation to get the last four. And do the same to extract the month from the last two.
Define new array variables `month` and `date` and allocate them to the same size as `day`, also add a new integer variable tmp and change your second loop to this:

```
    do j = 1,np-1
        year(j)=day(j)/10000
        tmp = mod(day(j), 10000)
        month(j) = tmp/100
        date(j) = mod(tmp,100)
    end do
```

I will also advise you to use free formatting for reading. You can use fixed format for writing to align data and make it easy to visualize.
Go for modern programming when you start. Litteral numbers are not a good idea in a code, so use named constants for file ids. Make sure that you close files when you do not need them anymore. When you are openning file for reading, use status='old', you want the file to be there or you want you program to stop with an appropriate message. When you are using format, use the format parameter of `read` and `write` instead of format statement, for example with the name arg `fmt` as you did at some places. This make it easy to debug. So your program could look like this.

```
program ascii_read
    !real(kind=8):: rain(np)
    integer, parameter :: inputId = 1243
    integer, parameter :: outputId = 12
    real,allocatable,dimension(:):: rain
    integer::np=12
    !integer(kind=8)::day(np)
    character(len = 80)::firstline
    integer::i,j, tmp
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:):: day, year, month, date

    allocate ( year(np-1), rain(np), day(np), month(np), date(np) )
    open(inputId,file="11700.text",status="old")
    open(outputId,file="11700_output.text",status="unknown")
    read(inputId,*)firstline  

    do i=2,np  
        read(inputId,*)day(i),rain(i)
    end do
    close(inputId)

    write(*,*) day
    do j = 1,np-1
        year(j)=day(j)/10000
        tmp = mod(day(j), 10000)
        month(j) = tmp/100
        date(j) = mod(tmp,100)
        ! just to see what we get.
        write(*, *) day(j), year(j), month(j), date(j)
    end do
    !write(*,fmt='(i4)')year
    !1 format(I4)
    !write(*,*)year

    return
    stop
end program
```

Thank to IanH for the comment, latest version of fortran included a newunit option that takes care of the IO unit number for programmers. This frees you from defining named constant for unit number. If you do not work with a latest version (Some companies do not upgrade often), there is one ready for use in [fortranwiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/newunit).

Comment: note he needs to fix the format to `i8` (or use a list directed read) for this to work..

Comment: @agentp, I tough a little bit about that and remember myself facing problems with those text files when someone all of the sudden for whatever reason, decided to add some space a the beginning. We had a hard time finding the problem. From that point on we decided that it will be free format (when reading numeric data). And when performance is an issue, use binary from the beginning.

Comment: Using list directed input to read user supplied data is error prone - it has a number of surprising features.  If you want to advocate modern programming, then ditch the constant unit numbers and use NEWUNIT.

Comment: @IanH, I totally agree with you. I did not think about it just because I do not work everyday with a version of fortran that support it. Luckily there is a simple one http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/newunit. I am upgrading the post.